# Generate alert box when mouse over image on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to generate an alert box when user moves his mouse on the star image. I tried to check the errors but I am not able to find error.

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Testing</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rating_style.css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#1_star").hover(function() {
            alert("hello");
        });

    });
</script>

 </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div class="rating-container">
            <div class="rating-star">
                <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="1_star" /> 

                <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="2_star" />
                <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="3_star" />
                <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="4_star" />
                <img src="sta.png" width="50" id="5_star" />
            </div>
       </div>
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should include jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#1_star").hover(function() {
            alert("hello");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9Lqz044k/)

> Note: This code will work .. but please searching for how to include
>   jquery or how to install jquery because there are different ways to do
>   that

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need both a mouse in and a mouse out (that is what hover is really for), you might want to use .mouseover() instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method :

```
<div onmousemove="alert('hello')">
    <p>onmousemove: <br> <span id="demo">Your Text</span></p>
</div>
```